# adb fails to authenticate but still connects

Tags: adb

I'm connecting to a phone on OpenSTF via `adb`.  Running

```
$ adb connect <url>:<port_no>
```

produces the message

```
failed to authenticate to <url>:<port_no>
```

However, `adb devices` shows the device and I can interact as expected with the phone.  What does the authentication failure mean and should it concern me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're connected to the phone via USB, you may need to run

```
$ adb tcpip 5555
```

See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless

Comment: I can connect to it without problem.

Comment: Could please write your environment?

Comment: Do you mean my environment variables or my OS info?

Comment: I want to know how your phone is connected to your pc. 
Failed to authenticate message means that the phone doesn't provide permisstions to wifi debug - wifi adb

Comment: I'm on a VPN connecting to the phone via an OpenSTF web GUI.

Comment: I understand how the phone is connected to the network, but I also need to understand how the phone is connected to the host.
Can you show the output of adb devices command on the host?

Comment: `some.url.lan:20973  device`

Comment: So you don't have access to the pc to which the phone is connected?
So could you please describe your connection scheme like:
phone with adb wifi (or adb usb with tcpip open port) <--> host pc with OpenSTF <--->  VPN network <---> Client with web gui

Comment: That I don't know.  I don't have physical access to the phone.

Comment: So I suppose that this is the reason: I mean that initially adb debug access of the phone to pc wasn’t granted.  While connecting the phone you should grant an access to pc.

Comment: After running `adb tcpip 20973` and reconnecting, I get the same message.

Comment: This command should be executed on the pc where the phone is connected. It is needed to open the debugging port

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'll ask the person in charge of the phone to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like sometimes the `adb` tooling changes.

I doubt you have had an old `adb` running in background that was still connected but try `adb kill-server`.

A new connect failed but an old connection is still open.

As for me, the pubkey has to be renewed on STF sometimes so remove it from OpenSTF and add your `adb` pub key (`~/.android/adbkey.pub`) again (even or especially when it tells you the key already is registered!).

Comment: No, good.  Same message.